# Atualizar o MemoryStream ao substituir BookMark

Tags: c#, microsoft-word

Galera, estou fazendo um serviço *RESTFUL* em C# que tem um método que recebe um *byte array* de um documento *WORD*, e nesse documento preciso substituir os bookmarks existentes por texto que também são passados no método.

- **Problema** : Ao realizar a substituição dos *bookmarks* pelo texto apropriado não consigo atualizar o *MemoryStream* para obter o *byte array* atualizado com as modificações no arquivo. Alguém já precisou trabalhar com o
- ReferenciaRelatorio

  ```
  public class ReferenciaRelatorio
  {
         public string referencia {get; set;}
         public object valor { get; set; }
   }
  ```
- RelatorioDS

  ```
   [DataContract]
   public class RelatorioDS
   {        
       [DataMember]
       public List<ReferenciaRelatorio> mapaDeSubstituicao { get; set; }
       /**arquivo binario na base 64**/
      [DataMember]
      public string template { get; set; }
   }
  ```
- GeradorRelatorioWord (**EDITADO**)

  ```
  using System;
  using System.IO;

  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
  using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
  using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
  using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;



  namespace RestService
  {
  public class GeradorRelatorioWord 
  {

     public ResponseData gerarRelatorio(RelatorioDS data)
     {
        ResponseData resposta =  new ResponseData();
        try
        {
           byte[] saida = null;
           byte[] template = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data.template);
           using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(template))
           {
              /**EDITADO**/
              /**mem.Write(template, 0, (int)template.Length);**/
             using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, false))
             {
               var bookMarks = recuperarBookMark(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document);
               substituirBookMark(data, bookMarks);
               byte[] buf;  
               Stream stream = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream();
               buf = new byte[stream.Length];  
               stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
               saida = buf ;


               /** EDITADO **/
               /**
               wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
               wordDoc.Close();
               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
               {
                 string documentoTexto = sr.ReadToEnd();

                 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                 {
                   sw.Write(documentoTexto);

                   MemoryStream me = new MemoryStream();
                   sw.BaseStream.CopyTo(me);
                   saida = me.ToArray();
                 }


               }**/

             }
             resposta.relatorio = System.Convert.ToBase64String(saida);

           }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

        resposta.erros.Add(new MensagemErro(e));

      }
      return resposta;
     }

     /**
     * Recupera os BookMarks que existirem
     **/
     private Dictionary<string, BookmarkEnd> recuperarBookMark(OpenXmlElement documentPart, Dictionary<string, BookmarkEnd> results = null, Dictionary<string, string> unmatched = null)
     {
        results = results ?? new Dictionary<string, BookmarkEnd>();
        unmatched = unmatched ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var child in documentPart.Elements())
        {
            if (child is BookmarkStart)
            {
              var bStart = child as BookmarkStart;
              unmatched.Add(bStart.Id, bStart.Name);
            }

            if (child is BookmarkEnd)
            {
              var bEnd = child as BookmarkEnd;
              foreach (var orphanName in unmatched)
              {
               if (bEnd.Id == orphanName.Key)
               results.Add(orphanName.Value, bEnd);
              }
            }

            recuperarBookMark(child, results, unmatched);
        }

        return results;
     }

     /**
     * substitui os bookmarks
     *
     *
     **/
     private static void substituirBookMark(RelatorioDS data, Dictionary<string, BookmarkEnd> bookMarks)
     {
        foreach (var end in bookMarks)
        {
          string bookmark = Uri.UnescapeDataString(end.Key);
          foreach (ReferenciaRelatorio entry in data.mapaDeSubstituicao)
          {
            if (bookmark.Equals(entry.referencia))
            {
              var textElement = new Text((string)entry.valor);
              var runElement = new Run(textElement);

              end.Value.InsertAfterSelf(runElement);
            }

          }

        }
     }


  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código que lida com a stream tem alguns problemas:

Primeiro: quando você escreve na *stream* `mem` o cursor da stream está no fim dela, o que pode fazer com que a sua leitura não funcione. Sugestão: troque o trecho de código

```
byte[] template = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data.template);
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    mem.Write(template, 0, (int)template.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
```

por

```
byte[] template = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data.template);
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(template))
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, false))
```

Segundo: a stream do documento do word não é necessariamente de texto; usar um `StreamReader` e converter para texto (usando o UTF-8 ou outro encoding padrão) provavelmente vai causar perda de dados. Troque o trecho

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
{
    string documentoTexto = sr.ReadToEnd();
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        sw.Write(documentoTexto);
        MemoryStream me = new MemoryStream();
        sw.BaseStream.CopyTo(me);
        saida = me.ToArray();
    }
}
```

por

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream()) {
    wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream().ToArray().CopyTo(mem);
    saida = mem.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: valeu pelas dicas. Só uma duvida,eu acho que a classe Stream não tem o metodo ToArray. Fiz as alterções da sua resposta, contudo o arquivo que obtenho do _byte_ _array_ ele fica corrompido. @carlosfigueira

Comment: Ah, esse é um *extension method* que eu tenho na minha biblioteca. Você pode copiar para um memory stream usando o `CopyTo` então.